# Getters & setters & utter confusion

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with my second class (MazeSolver) is not getting the values of **rows** and **cols** from my first class (MazeInput) as it should be. which is leading to *ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions* and *NullPointerExceptions* in my drawMaze() method in MazeSolver. I understand why these errors are happening, I am just clueless how to address it due to a lack of understanding of how to pass fields to other classes. Could you lovely guys please point out where I am going wrong?

```
public class LA2_MazeInput {

private int rows;
private int cols;

public LA2_MazeInput() {
    this.rows = getNumRows();
    this.cols = getNumCols(rows);
}

private int getNumRows() {

    int rows = 0;
    String input;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Please enter the number of rows (5-10) for the maze.");


    rows = Integer.parseInt(input);




    return rows;
}

private int getNumCols(int numRows) {

    int cols = 0;
    String input;



    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            "Please enter the number (5-10) of columns for the maze."
            + "\n(Value cannot be the same as the number of rows.)");


    cols = Integer.parseInt(input);




    return cols;
}

public void initializeMazeSolver(/*MazeSolver solver*/) {

    LA2_MazeSolver ms = new LA2_MazeSolver();
    ms.setNumRows(this.rows);
    ms.setNumCols(this.cols);




  }

}



public class LA2_MazeSolver {
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private String[][] maze;

    public LA2_MazeSolver() {

        this.maze = new String[rows][cols];
    }

public void setNumRows(int numRows) {

    this.rows = numRows;

}

public void setNumCols(int numCols) {

    this.cols = numCols;

}

public int getNumRows() {

    return this.rows;

}

public int getNumCols() {

    return this.cols;

}

public void drawMaze() {

    Random r = new Random();

    maze[0][0] = "S";
    maze[rows - 1][cols - 1] = "D";
    int limit = ((rows * cols) / 3);

    for (int i = r.nextInt(limit) + 1; i < limit; i++) {

        maze[r.nextInt(rows - 1)][r.nextInt(cols - 1)] = "#";

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < maze[0].length; c++) {

            if (!(maze[i][c].matches("#")) && !(maze[i][c].matches("S")) && !(maze[i][c].matches("D"))) {

                maze[i][c] = Integer.toString(r.nextInt(100) + 1);

            }

        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < maze[0].length; c++) {

            System.out.print(maze[i][c] + " ");

        }
        System.out.println();
    }


  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MazeSolver` constructor initializes your two dimensional array with the size of `[0][0]`. After that you try to set the rows and cols which it's too late at this point.

```
 LA2_MazeSolver ms = new LA2_MazeSolver(); // constructor of LA2_MazeSolver is called
 ms.setNumRows(this.rows); // does nothing for the array
 ms.setNumCols(this.cols); // does nothing for the array
```

In order to fix this you could just pass the parameters along with the constructor.

```
  public LA2_MazeSolver(int rows, int cols) {
        this.maze = new String[rows][cols];
        this.rows = rows; // in case you want them to store
        this.cols = cols; // in case you want them to store
    }
```

The antipattern:

```
public LA2_MazeSolver() {
    }

public void setNumRows(int numRows) {
    this.rows = numRows;
}

public void setNumCols(int numCols) {
    this.cols = numCols;
}

public void init(){
    this.maze = new String[rows][cols];
}
```

Would init it like this

```
 LA2_MazeSolver ms = new LA2_MazeSolver();
 ms.setNumRows(this.rows);
 ms.setNumCols(this.cols);
 ms.init();
```

Comment: I thought about that, but at that point would I even need the getters and setters?

Comment: @GregSmith As far as I can tell you don't need them.

Comment: That's half the problem...I want to do it with constructors. However I'm required to have the getters and setters and utilize them as my prof required we follow his "basic program design". Is there a way to do this with getters and setters?

Comment: @GregSmith That's a anti pattern. But you can do it by using a third method to initialize the Array. In the end it's all about that you can not change the size of an fixed array after setting the size. Otherwise you would have to create a new one. I edited my answer to show you an example

Comment: I emailed my prof to ask if I can do it differently than what the structure says. I definitely agree that it's an antipattern but we'll see if that changes anything. Thanks for your help man, I appreciate it.